# http: panic serving [::1]:57685: assignment to entry in nil map

Tags: json, api, go, vcf-vcard

I am trying to make a vcard using golang.My code is:

```
    var (
    // card is a map of strings to []*vcard.Field objects
    card vcard.Card

    // destination where the vcard will be encoded to
    enc = vcard.NewEncoder(destFile) 
)
var str []string


for i, entry := range k {


    if i!=2{
        str=append(str,k[i])


        card.SetValue(vcard.FieldFormattedName, strings.Join(str[:i],""))//panic occurs here
        fmt.Println(str)

    }else if i==2{
        card.SetValue(vcard.FieldTelephone, entry)
    }else{
        card.SetValue(vcard.FieldOrganization, entry)
    }




    // set the value of a field and other parameters by using card.Set
    card.Set(vcard.FieldName, &vcard.Field{
        Value: strings.Join(str[:2], ";"),
        Params: map[string][]string{
            vcard.ParamSortAs: []string{
                k[0] + " " + k[1],
            },
        },
    })
```

The json document which has to be stored in vcf is:

```
      {"firstname":"Vilas","lastname":"Prakash","mobile":"8732647482","organisation":"Dbjb"}
```

I have marshalled the json to []string.On executing I am getting the following error:

```
    http: panic serving [::1]:57685: assignment to entry in nil map
```

Can anyone help me???Or Is there any other way of creating .vcf or vcard in golang using json document as input???

Comment: Add a comment to the code indicating the line that panics.

Comment: commented the line where panic is occurring

Comment: "card vcard.Card" card is a map. And card.SetValue is assigning the value

Comment: `var card vcard.Card` you have created this as a global but you haven't initialized it. `var card = make(vcard.Card)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized your map. I suggest you read up on how maps work in Go https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

In the meantime

```
var card vcard.Card
```

should be

```
var card = make(vcard.Card)
```

I'm not familiar with the vcard data structure. But you mention that it should be a map -> string][]*vcard.Field.. If the above make fails change it to

```
var card = make(map[string][]*vcard.Field)
```